# VPN system tray icon has changed

Tags: vpn

I have a question on my vpn.

My VPN has always connected without incident however previously the system tray would always show a Ethernet icon when connected through the vpn

[image: etherneticon].

However for the past month it has switched to a wireless icon and not once changed back to ethernet icon. 
[image: wirelessicon]

I am not very tech savy but I just wanted to know why this is happening and if I need to check anything with my connection.

I have heard it might be related to microsofts Network Awareness, NCSI functionality Though i cannot confirm that. If it is the case I am hoping to understand why it switched over and its stayed with the wireless symbol for a month.

Comment: Which VPN client are you using? Version?

Answer (score 0):

The icon you are referring to is not the 'vpn' icon for Windows 10, it is used to indicate the network connection.
The first icon shows when you're connected to a wired network (you have an ethernet cable connected to your PC). The second is when you're connected using the Wi-Fi chip of your PC.

Is it possible that you switched from a wired network to WiFi?
Or you might have turned on your PC's WiFi (and are connected both wired and wireless).

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the network icon in your first image, if you click the up arrow just to the left, to show more icons?

If so, the order of connecting probably changed. In your first image, the computer would have started the VPN software first (the computer makes an internal "network" connection to the internal VPN software), and then connected to wifi (and then the VPN would have access to the outside world.  ---  In your second image, the wifi connection is happening first (you may not be secure at that point), and then the VPN is started and connected (assuming the VPN is actually running).

In the case of the second image, make sure you have a firewall setup up to block traffic that isn't going through the VPN, if that's what you want. Comodo firewall lets you do MAC filtering, so you can set the firewall so traffic (defined) can only go through the VPN.  (The VPN MAC is the "physical address" you see when you type "ip config /all" from a command prompt. Look for a TAP adapter in that list.) If the VPN is not connected, then there's no outside internet.